Does this proof that $\min_P ||APx||$ is NP-complete (for general $n\times n$ $A$, permutations $P$, and a vector $x$) work?
Let $A$ be some $n×n$ matrix, and $x$ be a column vector of length $n$. I am looking to find the permutation matrix $P$ of size $n×n$ that minimizes the vector norm of $APx$.
In a previous question for certain, non-symmetric $A$, it was convincingly shown that this problem is NP-complete, by reduction to 3-partition. However, I am now interested in more general $A$ matrices (in particular, those that are symmetric), and have sketched the following proof. I am NOT an expert in linear algebra, so would appreciate some insight.
Theorem. Consider a $n\times n$ matrix $A$, a column vector $x$ of length $n$, and the set of all $n\times n$ permutation matrices, particular such matrices denoted $P$.  The problem of minimizing the vector norm $||APx||$ over $P$ may be reduced to the quadratic assignment problem.
Proof.
Let us first recall the quadratic assignment problem. Given two sets, $W$ and $D$ of equal size, together with a weight function $w:W\times W\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a distance function $d:D\times D\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, find the bijection $f:W\longrightarrow D$ (i.e., assignment) such that the following cost function is minimized:
$$\min_{f} \sum_{a, b\in W}w(a,b)\cdot d(f(a),f(b))$$
With the weight and distance functions represented as square, real-valued matrices, we may re-write this as:
$$\min_{f}\sum_{a,b\in W}w_{a,b}\cdot d_{f(a),f(b)}$$
Now, turning to our case, we first consider the construction $APX$, where $X= [x, \mathbf{0},...,\mathbf{0}]$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix. This construction is such that the Frobenius norm of the $n\times n$ matrix of 1s ($\mathbf{1}$) and the element-wise square of $APX$, $\text{sq}(APX)$, is equal to the square of the vector norm $||APx||^2$. That is:
$$\sum_{i,j} \mathbf{1}_{i,j}\cdot\text{sq}(APX)_{i,j} = ||APx||^2$$
Therefore, we can identify the matrix $\mathbf{1}$ with the weight function, $\text{sq}(AX)$ with the distance function, and $P$ with the bijection (assignment) of the quadratic assignment problem. This completes our proof that $\min_P||APx||$ is a quadratic assignment problem.
Question.
Is this legitimate? It doesn't seem to be... The part in particular that I don't feel comfortable with is identifying $P$ with the bijection function $f$, even though it permutes the rows of $x$ ($X$). I suppose this is because it's not immediately clear to me that it is possible to write $\text{sq}(APX)$ in the form $d(f(a),f(b))$.
